# When to pass modules as arguments and when to use require again?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know the following...

- Calling 'require' loads up a module (file) and caches it.
- Subsequent calls to 'require' the same module will load the cached version.

Knowing this, we can assume that...

**file1.js**

```
var module = require('module');

module.name = 'lionpants';
```

**file2.js**

```
var module = require('module');

console.log(module.name); // "lionpants"
```

Using that knowledge I think that you would only pass instances of a module if you had to create an instance of it and wanted to reference the instance's state across modules. An example of that would be the popular Express module, where you pass an instance of your Express app created by the module.

- Are there any other cases where you would pass a module as an argument instead of just 'requiring' it again in the new module?
- Does a module like Mongoose open multiple connections if you don't pass the 'mongoose.connect('db')' instance around? IE: When using Models created with the same mongoose module.

Comment: In your Express example, you don't pass the *module* as an argument, but instead you pass in the result produced from calling the module as a function, right? (i.e., you pass `app` from `app = require("express")()`, not the `require("express")` value itself) I *think* you already understand that these are two very different things. Just to be clear, you are asking only about passing modules themselves, right?

Comment: Yes, I am just talking about passing modules themselves. I'll update my answer to clarify.